# Bugged arrow keys navigation with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all I'm new to JavaScript/jQuery and English isn't my mother tongue.

In this case I can't use anything more than jQuery/JavaScript (I mean no other plugin/library, anything that I haven't coded myself).

I wanna make a website with arrow keys navigation, using overflow:hidden on my body, and scrollTop.

## Here is what I already have :

```
<div id="slide1">
    <div id="states">
        <div id="selector"></div>
        <div id="state1"><p>INTRO</p></div>
        <div id="state2"><p>STAGE 1</p></div>
        <div id="state3"><p>STAGE 2</p></div>
        <div id="state4"><p>STAGE 3</p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2">
</div>

<div id="slide3">
</div>

<div id="slide4">
</div>
```

As i named it a bit randomly, i'll have to explain :
  - slide1 is my first "state" or "screen". It's a big container where I put informations about how to navigate through the website, as it's the first thing the user will see, we directly land on that state.
  - slide 2, 3, 4 : other big blocks will see if they navigate through the website, step by step.
  - state 1, 2, 3, 4 are buttons at the top of the document (position:fixed). By clicking on it, the user can jump to slide 1, 2, 3 or 4.
  - selector is only a design thing, if you're on slide x he puts himself on state x, that shows the user where he is in the page.

## Now the JQuery part :

### Variables I use :

```
var pressedKeys = {};
var state = [0,1200,2400,3600];
var slidestate = [0, 25, 50, 75];
var n = 0;
```

var state: contains in an array values I use for my scrollTop (for now each  are 1200px height long.)
var slidestate : contains in an array values my selector (the thing that shows the user where he is) margin (in %)

### Obtaining keyCode :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) {
    n++;
    if (n>3){n--;}
}
else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38){
    n--;
    if (n<0){n++;}
    }
```

So n = the state where I am. I don't want it to be < 0 or > 3 that's why I use "if n>3 n--" in that case, as I have only 4 states (and my array start with a 0 index, so 0 1 2 3 = the 4 states I need).

### Using var n to scroll (keyboard) :

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated),#basmontagne:not(:animated)").animate({

     scrollTop:state[n]
     },1000);

$(" #selector ").animate({left:slidestate[n]+'%'},1000);

});
```

I don't think I have to explain anything here, I use n as the index of my array containing values I need for every state. Animation duration is 1 second.

### Using var n to scroll (.click event) :

```
$("#state1").click(function() {
        n=0;

        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated),#basmontagne:not(:animated)").animate({
        scrollTop:state[n] },1000); 

    $(" #selector ").animate({left:slidestate[n]+'%'},1000);
});
```

Same as below but with my  and an onClick event.

## The problem

The code below IS working. But there is some things I'm not able to fix. It all seems laggy, sometimes scrollTop seems to not be working;

> Case 1 : I'm at the 4th state, I press "down" arrow key once, then press "up" arrow key once. It should jump to state 3, but it doesn't. I have to press "up" once again, and then it jumps to state 2. what the heck?
>
> Case 2 : I don't know why but sometimes, when I navigate through the site, the selector moves, but scrollTop doesn't do anything. So my selector goes to state 3 where I'm only on state 1. Again what the heck? It should be the same value of n for scrollTop and selector, I don't get why it's all bugged like this.

Anyone got any idea about this ?

Comment: You might be hitting an issue with the keycode detection, consider having only the `if` statements instead of incrementing and thrn decrementing `n` one after another.

Comment: In the first html code snippet you are opening more DIVs than you close.

Comment: @AllInOne Yes sorry I'm editing this, that happened when I deleted some content so the code wasn't polluted with useless stuff.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha I tried your solution, using scrollTop: scroll, with scroll += 1200 when I press down/right, and scroll -= 1200 when i press up or left. I used if (scroll>3600) {scroll -= 1200} but when I reach last state and press down again (even once), then I can't go back to previous states (even if I press up or left multiple times). I don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I couldn't clearly understand what you are trying to do on the extreme cases, i.e, n>3 and n<0. If your attempt was to just do nothing then you can reduce the redundancy in that bit by using,

```
if ((e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) && (n < 3))
    n = n + 1;
else if ((e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38) && (n > 0))
    n = n - 1;
```

instead of,

```
if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) {
    n++;
    if (n>3){n--;}
}
else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38){
    n--;
    if (n<0){n++;}
}
```

that makes it a little more debuggable,

Coming to your main issues...
Case 1 and Case 2 are because of the same problem, actually not a problem but something that was used incorrectly.

The `:animated` filter, [read more about animated filter](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

So by writing,
    `$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated),#basmontagne:not(:animated)")
        .animate({ scrollTop:state[n] },1000);`

you are selecting the html, body and #basmontagne elements which are **not in animation**.

The issue of value of n and scrollTop not being synced at all times, precisely happens when the value of n changes **in middle of an animation**, because the html, body etc are in animation at that moment and are skipped by the jQuery selector, thus animation callback doesn't work at that instance.

In [**this fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq7yd/3/) if you keep your console open you will see the value of n and scrollPosition are always on track.

If in your code this does not work it may be because the `var n` is globally defined and some other section of code is modifying it.

Lastly, you may also want to check the `.stop()` in jQuery which may make the animation better.

Hope that helps.!!

Comment: Hi shoaib, sorry I didn't read it quick. Thanks for your answer, it sure helped me to figure out some beginner mistakes. I'll try it out !